# Why google allow some company to have 2 account google play developer?

Tags: google-play-console

A few months ago my developer account is got banned because Google detects my account have associated but I never have associated with other developers. Then I see a company named Dicoding.in the play store that company has 2 accounts named Dicoding ID 1 and Dicoding ID 2.why that company can make 2 accounts? If see my case it very unfair

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming in any of the senses acceptable hereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule preventing ap app developer from having two accounts.

However, if an account is associated with *other developer accounts that get banned* then that account may also be banned. This is to prevent bad developers who break the rules or create malware just creating new accounts.

Google don't publish how they detect associations for obvious reasons: if they did then bad developers would just avoid doing those things.